# Is there any way to use a non Int32 value for Cellspacing in ASP?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I want the cell spacing to be 0.5 for an ASP GridView.  Is there any way to accomplish this as it tries to cast the value to Int32 and obviously 0.5 will not cast to Int32.  I want it this way because IE expresses really ugly cell separators, but if I set CellSpacing to 0 or remove it, the cells are way too crowded.

IE9 with CellSpacing = 3:

[image: Grid in IE9 3px]

IE9 with CellSpacing = 0:

[image: Grin in IE9 0px]

Chrome with CellSpacing = 3:

[image: Grid in Chrome 3px]

Chrome with CellSpacing = 0

[image: Grid in Chrome 0px]

Setting it to 1 is ok, but I was hoping there was some way to do less.

Comment: CellSpacing is measured in pixels. 1 is as good as you're gonna get I think.

Comment: I know it is,  but IE I think recognizes decimal pixels,  Chrome and FF truncate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<asp:GridView 
   CellPadding = "5";
   GridLines="Vertical" />
```

Comment: even if it is ok (don't know), please some explanatory text as to WHY -- like in school the solution alone isn't everything :)

Comment: That fixed the too close issue by padding the internal cells some.  and I was able to leave it at 0 which looks best in both browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of but then I much prefer to give my elements a CssClass that way I can define everything I want (aspx has some weird ideas) and achieve a universal look throughout the site.

Shout if you need a hand with the css.

Comment: using the CSS Class "Directory"  on my aspnet GridView, I put the following in my css file:

    Directory
    {
 empty-cells: show;
        border-collapse:separate;
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        border-width:1px;
        column-gap:0.5px;
        CellSpacing=5px;
    }

I also tried 

    Directory
    {
 empty-cells: show;
        border-collapse:separate;
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        border-width:1px;
        column-gap:0.5px;
        CellSpacing:5px;
    }

neither worked.